# выбрать дочерний элемент у дочернего

Tags: html, css

Есть простой список, в нем иконки соц.сетей из fontawesome, по умолчанию черно-белые. По наведению на иконку у нее должен смениться бэкграунд на цветной, а шрифт стать белым вместо черного. Но иконка вложена еще и в ссылку, поэтому через + я ее достать не могу. Есть какие-то другие способы достать дочерний элемент у дочернего?

```css
.fb:hover {
  border: none;
  background-color: #4267B2;
    
}

.fb + fa-fa-facebook {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<li class="socials__item fb">
<a href="#" class="socials__icon">
<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Я б добавил transition: all 100ms;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы просто не убрать `+`?

```css
.fb .fa-facebook {
  color: #000;
}

.fb .fa-facebook:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4267B2;
}
```

```html
<li class="socials__item fb">
  <a href="#" class="socials__icon">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true">A</i>
  </a>
</li>
```